# Data integration ETL with java web application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, pentaho, etl, talend, data-integration

I'm newbie with **Business intelligence** , and I'm going to develop a java web application.
I want to `integrate` data from different sources so then I can store them in a database .
Is there an API or jars of pentaho or talend or other `ETLs` that I can add to my application to do that ??
Or what shall I do ??

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle) you can follow those instructions:
http://pentaho-bi-suite.blogspot.cz/2015/03/kettle-etl-basics-5-command-line.html

It instructs you to develop ETL job in Kettle and then schedule it. ETL job is developed in [Pentaho Data Integration](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/) tool. It is possible to load data from various sources (databases, files, etc.), transform them and load to a target database.

This way the ETL is not a part of you Java web application. It simply coexist as a separate application.

Comment: Thanks for your response :)

Comment: But Do you know if there is a afree  API or libarary  that makes me do the  data integration in my web application ??

Comment: So, do you want to integrate the core functionality of ETL tool to your application?

Comment: Spoon (Pentaho ETL) is designed for users who is not familiar with java programming. Most powerful feature of Pentaho ETL is visual designer for transformations/jobs and clustering out of the box. And it came with a lot of functionality you a really don't need at all. If you have something but not use it - it just waste of memory. When you speak about 'data integration' - it is very common question. Without knowing of what exact integration do you want it is hard to suggest any tools best silver-bullet tools.

Comment: Yes, Pentaho has an entire Java API, but I would consider whether you really need to do that, especially with the Kettle Thin JDBC Driver. Here's the [Kettle API Docs](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Pentaho+Data+Integration+-+Java+API+Examples).

Comment: Thanks @Brian.D.Myers the link you gave  is very useful .. this [link](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Freporting_embedders_guide%2Ftopic_embedding_engine.html) also is helpful. :)

Comment: Yes @mzy that's what I'm looking for .

Answer (score 0):

You could use this https://github.com/rodrifmed/pentaho-data-integration

In this repo have a example of use and a simple wrapper of pentaho's java api